# Replacing links with var

Tags: jquery, html, replace, href

I am trying to replace a link with a var but the page being loaded is example.com/$NewLink instead of the value of the variable, I am sure this has been asked already but I could not seem to strum up the answer.

Current Code:

```
$('[href="Link"]').attr('href', '$NewLink');
```

Thanks

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes on `$NewLink` assuming it is a defined variable

Comment: Show us your HTML so we see the link you're trying to manipulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$NewLink is a variable, not a string.  Remove the quotes:

```
$('[href="Link"]').attr('href', $NewLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around $NewLink